# Grails createCriteria not returning any results

Tags: grails, groovy, createcriteria

I'm trying to use the createCriteria in a grails application to return some rows from a DB. I'm not getting any results.

```
def query = {
    ilike('fullName','%${params.term}%')
    projections {
        property('id')
        property('fullName')
    }   
}

def plist = Patient.createCriteria().list(query) 
def patientSelectList = []
plist.each {
    def pMap = [:] 
    pMap.put("id", it[0])
    pMap.put("label", it[1])
    pMap.put("value", it[1])
    patientSelectList.add(pMap) 
}
```

the fields i'm looking for exist as the following snippet returns results but is very slow.

```
def patientList = Patient.getAll()
def patientSelectList = []
patientList.each { patient ->
    if (patient.fullName.toLowerCase().contains(params.term.toLowerCase()) ) {
        def pMap = [:]
        pMap.put("id", patient.id)
        pMap.put("label", patient.fullName)
        patientSelectList.add(pMap)
    }
 }
return patientSelectList
```

thanks for anyhelp

I had my Db fields encryted with jasypt. Removing the encryption on the field I needed to query fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `String` rather than a `GString` in the `ilike()` parameter, so `params.term` is not being evaluated. To use a `GString`, use double-quotes instead.

```
ilike('fullName',"%${params.term}%")
```

Also make sure `%` is an appropriate wildcard character for your database (it probably is).

Comment: You'll have to keep troubleshooting.  For instance, try hard-coding the parameter value, try it without the i like, etc. I don't see anything wrong with the rest of the query.

Comment: Even if I hard code in the string i'm getting nothing back.

Comment: Get with me on Google Hangouts. I can help you get the query working. https://plus.google.com/u/0/109886199751744223967/about/p/pub